# Why do maximum memory size that 32-bit systems consume is 4 GB?

Tags: memory, memory-management

In 32-bit systems, 2^32 different address can be generate. Each address' size is 32 bit. So 2^32 x 32 gives us maximum memory size (bit). But it's equal with 16 GB. I don't understand. This must be 4 GB but not?

Comment: Each addressed location holds 1 byte, not 4 bytes... (and also, 2^32 * 32 does not equal 16 GB)

Comment: Each address' size is 32 bit. for example 0x83838382 is 32 bit address. i.e. 4 byte @obe

Comment: 2^32 * 32 = 137,438,953,472 bit

Comment: The size of the address is 32 bit but it points at a single byte. So you are limited to 32-bit worth of bytes, i.e. 2^32 bytes, i.e. 4GB.

Comment: How this mechanism works? How 32-bit address maps with just a single byte? @obe

Comment: Just like your address consists of multiple characters but maps to just a single house (or apartment)... the address `0` maps to byte #1. The address `1` maps to byte #2, the address `0x6251BC11` maps to byte #0x6251BC12, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because 2^32 = 4294967296 = 4 GiB.

Comment: 2^32 is maximum address number not size.

Comment: 32 bit addressing: 0101.0101.0100.1010.1010.0010.1010.1110 Each number can be 0 or 1. there are 2^32 addreess. Each address' size is 32 bit. So we have to multiply them.

Comment: @HakanDuran If the address size is 32 bits, it means that you are using 32 bits to represent an address. 32 bits give you 2^32 possible different combinations, so there are 2^32 possible addresses. To get the actual addressable memory size, you need to know the word length of the memory (i.e. size of memory cell that you are addressing). If your memory is made of bytes, then you can address 2^32 * 1 bytes of memory. If your memory is made of 64-bit words, then you can address 2^32 * 8 bytes, etc.